# CTRL+C No longer working for SSH from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ssh, putty

I have searched and searched for a solution to this but I have come up empty. I have been using PuTTy for some time now and sometime over the past month or so <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will no longer stop the current process, it will actually close the connection. ie. if I ran TOP, when I am done I would press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to return to the terminal.

AFAIK, I have not changed anything. Up-to-date on all Windows 10 updates. Also the machine I want to get into runs a script every time I login and I can't cancel it so I can't get into the machine at all to change anything if need be.

Should also add that it doesn't work in Bash either.

Comment: This has hardly anything to do with Windows 10. Either you changed PuTTY configuration or something on the server must have changed.

Comment: Ok, fair enough, but that's why I am asking. I don't know that it was nothing to do with Win10, maybe the OS intercepts them before. If there is a PuTTY config for it, then what would it be? Again, I have not touched the config since I put it in. If there is a config on the server, what would it be? It's just running Pi-Hole.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with PuTTY, a simple way around it is to "Ctrl + Right Click" will bring up some options. Choose "Special Command -> SIGINT"

Answer (score 0):

In short the solution is:

> Take a terminal that works.

1. I find one working `gitbash v2.32.0.windows.`.

The latest available `gitbash` currently is `v2.38.1`. But only the old one is working correctly with `Vagrant(Oracle VM)`. The strange thing is that the latest one (`gitbash  v2.38.1`) is working fine with SSH connections to AWS EC2 instances.

2. Alternatively. `Windows PowerShell` is working fine with Vagrant(Oracle VM).

---

If someone needs my **bad experience**, here it is.
The following terminals DON'T WORK

- gitbash v2.38.1 (latest for now)
- gitbash V2.36.0
- ConEmu v220807 Alhpa (latest for now)
- cmder v1.3.20.1282 (latest for now)